# trouble restoring home directory from backup

Tags: home-directory, restore, duplicity

I was using an old version of Ubuntu, made a backup of /home/user on an external HD, installed the much newer Ubuntu 17.04 (formatting the old machine), and now am trying to restore /home/user.

I can restore single files and directories using the command

```
duplicity restore --no-encryption --file-to-restore home/user/path-to-file file:///media/user/HD/ /home/user/filename
```

However, when I try restore /home/user using

```
duplicity --no-encryption file:///media/user/HD/ /home/user/
```

I get the error

> Restore destination directory /home/user already exists.
>   Will not overwrite.

And when I try restore /home/user to a new directory,

```
duplicity --no-encryption file:///media/user/Maxtor/ /home/user/RESTORED/
```

(where RESTORED is a new directory) it gives me a whole bunch of errors of the form

> Error '[Errno 36] File name too long: '/home/user/RESTORED/home/user/.kde/share/...

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your current `/home/user` with `sudo mv /home/user /home/user1` and then restore with your first command.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--force` flag will let you restore on existing folder:

```
duplicity --no-encryption --force file:///media/user/HD/ /home/user/
```

Credit to other answer on different SO:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154061/151098